# Main function in .lib as startup function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cross-platform

I want to do something like this:

library.h

```
#define main ClientMain
```

libary.cpp

```
#define main ClientMain
extern "C" int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);

#ifdef WINDOWS
int WINAPI WinMain()
{
  // other code here
  ClientMain(0, 0, 0);
}
#endif
```

client.cpp // platform independent code

```
#include library.h
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ // stuff}
```

However, I keep getting the error:
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I solved the issue. In addition to what Rob pointed out, extern "C" int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]); that line is wrong because it did not match the prototype as in client.cpp

Comment: You'll probably save yourself some confusion, at least during your initial development, if you get rid of that macro and refer to all your functions by their real names. Incidentally, the *real* `main` function doesn't necessarily have "C" linkage; its linkage is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling your Windows program as a console program. In that case, the expected entry point really is `main`, not `WinMain`. The latter is for GUI programs. Your program has a function named `WinMain` and a function named `ClientMain`, but no `main`.

It's fine if you want your library to provide the `main` function, but you have to make sure it's really named `main`, because that's what the linker will be looking for.

Comment: After solving this issue I still get a similar error message -Library.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ClientMain referenced in function _WinMain@16

Comment: That means you no longer have a function named `ClientMain`, so what is `WinMain` supposed to call? Note that C++ forbids *you* from calling `main`. Seems to me you need three functions. `WinMain` and `main` should *both* call `ClientMain`.